# Looping data from a recordset: switch from VBA to VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, recordset

I've learned (by myself) a little bit of VBA and now I'm attempting to transfer some code in VB.net

To extract data from mySql Database I adapted this code:

```
Cn.Open("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & _
    ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Uid=" & UserDB & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";")
SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM errlog WHERE Data > NOW()-100000"
rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
rs.Open(SQLStr, Cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then mRS_Result = rs.GetRows()
If rs.State Then rs.Close()
```

So, to loop all data in a column of the extracted records, I usually:

```
NumCol = 0
For NumRow = 0 to mRS_Result.GetUpperBound(1)
    myValue = mRS_Result(NumCol, NumRow)
Next NumRow
```

following the advice received, I Changed approach to .net way and now I'm using this code:

```
cnString = "datasource=" + Server_Name + ";username= " + UserDB + _
    ";password=" + Password + ";database=" + Database_Name + ""
sqlQRY = "SELECT * FROM errlog WHERE Data > NOW()-100000"
conn = New MySqlConnection(cnString)
Try
    conn.Open()
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn)
    Dim cb As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(ds, "" + TextBox3.Text + "")
Catch ex As Common.DbException
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

So, to loop all data in a column of the extracted records, I'm using this code:

```
NumCol = 0
For NumRow = 0 to ds.Tables(0).Rows.count -1
    myValue = ds.Tables(0).Rows(NumRow ).item(NumCol).tostring
Next NumRow
```

My questions are:

Is this a correct .net way?

".ToString" is useful? Also when data is numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this code seams ok (it would compile and work as expected) this is not how you should do this with .NET

There are several improvements I would suggest.

- MySQL connector has a Helper class that is the recommanded way to use the lib
- Make use of the Using Keyword for Disposable objects like DataSet or MySqlConnection (and avoid closing your connection)
  Using is basically a shortcut for `Try obj = ... Finally obj.Dispose() End Try`
- Use ForEach instead of a For look
- Don't loop over DataTable.Rows but DataTable.DefaultView
- Access columns per name and not per index
- Don't use ToString() unless you want a string, prefer casting to the appropriate type

So your code should look like this

```
Dim connectionString As String = "..."
Dim query as String = "..."

Using ds As DataSet = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString, query)
    For Each row As DataRowView In ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        Dim value As Integer = CType(row("name"), Integer)
        ' Or if column can be null, use a Nullable<integer>
        Dim value As Integer? = If(DBNull.Value.Equals(row("name")), Nothing, CType(row("name"), Integer?))
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, I will study the advice. Only a stupid question (my knowledge is limited): How do I access the HelperClass?

Comment: @genespos `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper` - It is a class in `MySql.Data.dll` with some static methods.
While it may seem strange for someone coming from VBA not to keep an permanent connection to the database, in .NET it is quit common to use this pattern `Create Connection -> Open -> Make your query ->  Close connection`. The MySqlHelper itself hides this logic for you and just returns the data.
The MySql Connector itself keeps connections open in the background by default which are recycled, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html